# Почему не работает затемнение фона?

Tags: css, css3

Суть такая, хочу сделать затемнение фона при открытии модального окна, но почему когда у меня есть параметры: top = 0; bottom = 0; left = 0; и right = 0 - то затемнение фона есть, но когда я убираю например все, кроме top, оно исчезает, как это работает? Как позиционирование влияет на затемнение?

```
.modalWindowList {
    visibility: hidden; /* скрываем модальное окно */
    opacity: 0; /* делаем прозрачным */
    position: fixed; /* делаем блок фиксированным */
    top: 31px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    background: rgba(18,18,18,0.8); /* фон для затемнения */
    z-index: 9999; /* перекрываем все элементы */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы убираете значение `top`, оставляя при этом `bottom`, `left` и `right`, то ваше модальное окно "цепляется" за низ окна, левую и правую сторону, но не за верх. Соответственно, размер такого элемента равен всей ширине окна браузера по горизонтали, и 0px по вертикали.

Comment: То есть в моем случае данные поля необходимо оставить?

Comment: @Марьяна, да. (ещё два символа)